# zipping file creates odd file archive structure

Tags: java, zip

Current file location: `C:\bearCave\bear.mp3`

I want to zip it such that it will appear as a zip file in `C:\bearCave` as `bear.zip`. In `bear.zip`, I just want to see `bear.mp3` with no intermediary folders.

In other words, file structure should be:

```
bear.zip
 - bear.mp3
```

I managed to zip the file, which is generated in the correct location `C:\bearCave`. Interestingly, within that zip file, there is another folder `bearCave` which contains my file like so:

```
   bear.zip
    - C: 
     - bearCave
      - bear.mp3
```

EDIT 1: A possible clue, `outfilename=C:\bearCave\bear.zip`

Here's my code:

```
    String[] filenames = new String[]{file.getPath()};
    int dirEnd = (file.getPath()).indexOf(file.getName());
    String fileDirectory=file.getPath().substring(0, dirEnd);
    Logger.debug("dirEnd="+dirEnd);
    Logger.debug("fileDir="+fileDirectory);
    String outFilename = fileDirectory + (file.getName()).substring(0, ((file.getName()).length())-4) + ".zip";
    Logger.debug("outFile=" + outFilename);
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));

    for (int i=0; i<filenames.length; i++) {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filenames[i]);

        // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filenames[i]));

        // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            Logger.debug("len = " + len);
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        // Complete the entry
        out.closeEntry();
        in.close();
        Logger.debug("entry clsoed");
    }

    // Complete the ZIP file
    out.close();
    Logger.debug("zipping complete!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.error(e);
    Logger.debug(e);
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
fileName = bear.mp3
filePath = C:\bearCave\bear.mp3
fileDir=C:\bearCave\
outFile=C:\bearCave\bear.zip
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 1024
len = 508
entry clsoed
zipping Complete!
```

Comment: what does `winrar` do here?

Comment: double-clicking on the zip file brings me to winrar because its a default application for me. Winrar shows me there is a folder `C:` wihtin the archive, and within that another folder `bearCave` and within that `bear.mp3`

Comment: OK, so `winrar` has got nothing to do with this question here. Also, can you execute this command `jar tvf bear.zip` and paste the output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's your `filenames[]` array populated with? I think the problem is this line:

```
// Add ZIP entry to output stream.
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filenames[i]));
```

As I see it, `filenames[i]` is the whole path to your file and the `ZipEntry` will create this strange structure for you since it parses the given path into its "own" directory structure. Try creating the `ZipEntry` only with the designated filename (without the path component).

Comment: `filenames = new String[]{file.getPath()};` where file is the `File` object pointing to `bear.mp3`

Comment: Yeah, so have you tried only creating the `ZipEntry` with the files name? I.e. `new ZipEntry(file.getName())`?